# Run SQL query with python in SQL Server raises error: SqlSatelliteCall error: Unsupported input data type in column

Tags: sql-server, python

I am trying to run Python in SQL Server and want to define a variable which contains the result of a simple select query.

```
exec sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'python', @script = N'

import pandas as pd
inventory = pd.DataFrame(sql_inventory)

',
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT top 10 * from inventory',
@input_data_1_name = N'sql_inventory'
```

The structure of the SQL server table (inventory) is as below:

```
ProductID numeric(18,3)
RegionID numeric(18,3)
ShopCode int
QTY float
Date varchar(6)
Amount float
ID bigint
```

But I get the below error:
A 'Python' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004. Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 An external script error occurred:

> Unsupported input data type in column 'ProductID'. Supported types:
>   bit, tinyint, smallint, int, bigint, uniqueidentifier, real, float,
>   char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, varbinary. SqlSatelliteCall error:
>   Unsupported input data type in column 'ProductID'. Supported types:
>   bit, tinyint, smallint, int, bigint, uniqueidentifier, real, float,
>   char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, varbinary. STDOUT message(s) from
>   external script: SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the
>   console output for more information. Traceback (most recent call
>   last): File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py",
>   line 406, in rx_sql_satellite_call rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall",
>   params) File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py",
>   line 291, in rx_native_call ret = px_call(functionname, params)
>   RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.

Should I specify data types every time I want to read from a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the error messge can be misleading. In this case it's not. You're trying to use unsupported data type:

> Unsupported input data type in column 'ProductID'. Supported types:
>   bit, tinyint, smallint, int, bigint, uniqueidentifier, real, float,
>   char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, varbinary.

These two columns are causing the error:

```
ProductID numeric(18,3)
RegionID numeric(18,3)
```

According to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/python/python-libraries-and-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15#python-and-sql-data-types), `bigint` is the **SQLtype** equivalent to `numeric` **Python type**.

Please, try to run your code like this:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'python', @script = N'

import pandas as pd
inventory = pd.DataFrame(sql_inventory)

',
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT TOP 10 ShopCode, QTY, Date, Amount, ID FROM inventory',
@input_data_1_name = N'sql_inventory'
```

If I'm right, it should run fine. Since both columns `ProductID` and `RegionID` are numeric type you must either [CAST or CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) those columns to refer to them in the query, but beware of the possibility of [precision loss when converting from numeric to float or real](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#restrictions).

> Should I specify data types every time I want to read from a query?

No. Just use the supported data types and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Ronaldo. That was right but since the data types of the sql server are set to these types, then I have to cast or convert these columns each time I want to read this table, right? and that tedious I guess :(

Comment: @mpy If you're gonna write **too many** queries like that, another possibility would be having a `VIEW` of that table with the `CAST` or `CONVERT` of those columns on the `VIEW`. That way you would write the convertion only once and call the `VIEW` on your queries.

Answer (score 1):

This [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/python/python-libraries-and-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15) explains what is happening fairly clearly, and the error message is fairly clear as well.

What it boils down to is that Python does not support `Numeric` or `Decimal` data types, as well as some other SQL Server data types, such as `DateTime` or any of the Geolocation data items.  Thus, to work with these data types, you have to use different techniques.

[This StackOverflow item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238249/pyodbc-returning-decimal100-00) has some good information on using pandas to handle this process, as well as some other items.